# About scanf in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I´m trying to read a string which size i store previously in a variable L.

So, for example, if the size is 3 characters, then i would read it like this:

```
fscanf(read,"%.3s",pointer);
```

BUT in this case i will not know the size of the string, as i said earlier, the size i stored in a variable.

I´ve tried using nothing ( because i have no ideia how to do this). i can´t post this question for some reason if i don´t write this i think so ignore this sentence please, or if you can suggest me what i did wrong go ahead.Then what should i do? how can i change the "3" in "%.3s" to the variable that contains the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using fgets :

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

According to man:

> fgets()  reads in at most one less than size characters from stream
>   and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Read‐
>          ing stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null  byte  ('\0')
>          is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Code sample :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

        int length = 0;

        puts("Length of the string : ");
        scanf("%d ", &length);

        char string[length];

        fgets(string,length,stdin);

        puts(string);

return 0;

}
```

or you can use malloc :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

        int length = 0;
        char *string = NULL;

        puts("Length of the string : ");
        scanf("%d ", &length);

        string = malloc((length+1) * sizeof *string);

        fgets(string,length,stdin);

        puts(string);

        free(string);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: @killezio please, accept one of the two answer, also, if we helped you, you can click the up vote button :)

Comment: In your second example, you must `malloc` space for one more char.

Comment: It works now, but is bad code style because it would fail if the element type is changed later on, e.g., to a 2-byte unicode char. It should be `malloc((length+1) * sizeof *string);` which is portable.

Comment: @MartinZabel thank you for these fixes. As as student I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically generate the format string that you pass to `fscanf`.  For example:

```
sprintf(fmt, "%%.%ds", n);
```

If `n` is 3, then `fmt` will contain `%.3s` for example.  You can then pass `fmt` as the format argument to `fscanf`.  You will need to allocate space for `fmt` of course, but it should be simple to place an upper bound on the amount of space needed.